# Is it possible to pass GET or POST variable to external javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to pass GET or POST variable to external javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790119/is-it-possible-to-pass-get-or-post-variable-to-external-javascript)

I am wondering whether is it possible to pass any variable to **external** java-script file

**For example**

I have **this**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="gallery.js"></script>
```

**I'd like to know** if it's possible to pass an argument to that script file, and if so, how  do I read it in the external file? Something like this perhaps:???

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js?id=123"></script>
```

**Thank you**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using javascript alone, you can do it this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function $_GET(q,s) { 
    s = s ? s : window.location.search; 
    var re = new RegExp('&'+q+'(?:=([^&]*))?(?=&|$)','i');

    return (s=s.replace(/^?/,'&').match(re)) ? (typeof s[1] == 'undefined' ? '' : decodeURIComponent(s[1])) : undefined;

}  </script>
```

And then use the javascript function this way:

```
// this code would print "hello world" if it was at http://localhost/index.php?var1=hello&var2=world
var var1 = $_GET('var1');
var var2 = $_GET('var2');
document.write(var1 + " " + var2);
```

Full credit should go to Josh Fraser, from whom I paraphrased this answer.

http://www.onlineaspect.com/2009/06/10/reading-get-variables-with-javascript/

Comment: I had an Invalid Quantifier error with this code (under firefox 30.0), I needed to escape the `?` with a backslash in the argument of `s.replace`.

Answer (score 1):

In my example i am taking server side language as php -

You can include this in your html file -

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var Str = "<?php echo $variable;?>";
</script>
```

Now variable Str will be available in all external js files.

Comment: @Dan Grossman: Before giving downvote atleast read my answer first. I have clearly written that in my example i am taking server side language as php because @Wazzy havent mentioned which server side language he is using.